# Pycharm type hinting to a class

Tags: python, class, pycharm, type-hinting

I want to build a class that requires an object from a different class to initialize.

So in script `a.py` I would have:

```
class A():
    pass
```

and in script `b.py` I have

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, data):
        """

        :type data: A 
        """
        pass
    pass

class C():
   pass
```

I am using PyCharm and I would like to use their type hinting, because I would like to use methods from class A inside class B and it would be easier having the support whenever I do so. But when I start typing after `:type data:` all I see are the classes defined in the second script. I tried `a.A` and `.a.A` but nothing leads to PyCharm knowing afterwords where to get the documentation for the methods used on `data`.

Comment: how are you importing A into your script b?

Comment: have you added something like `from a import A` to your script b

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, omg, I did not try that because I do not call the class inside B and I thought it would lead to a warning from PyCharm that the class remained unused, but it worked instead. Thank you!